# JavaFX BorderPane multi FXML space arrangement and transition effect

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, borderpane

i want to design a GUI that contains BorderPane in the top of the container there is a MenuBar, in the left of the container there is a Acordion with different buttons that change the content of the center of the container for diferent FXML files, someting like the desktop app of Spotiffy

[image: http://s32.postimg.org/4qw5qbr45/Spoty_Like.png]

i got a working prototipe and it looks like this

[image: http://s32.postimg.org/w9g4rqfid/muestra.png]

the change in FXML happens and the buttos respont very well, the problem i have is that the FXML that fill the center part of the BoderPane doesn't auto rize and if is to big parts of the FXML doesn't show and if the FXML is smaller that the space left for the center part stays of the same small size and left alot of space with nothing

this is my code for the calling of the new FXML

```
public void lanzaUno(){
        try {
            // load first FXML
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

            loader.setLocation(Coordinador.class.getResource(
                    "VistaControlador/Usuario/Uno.fxml"));

            /*i put the AnchorPane inside of a 
            ScrollPane  for the desire funcionality of alot 
            of vertical space for many nodes in a single FXML file  
            */
            ScrollPane unoAnchorPane = (ScrollPane) loader.load();

            UnoController controller = loader.getController();
            //example method for passing variables to the FXML controler 
            controller.pasoPrincipal(this, primaryStage, "Rhutt");
            //puts the FXML in the center of the BorderPane
            rootLayout.setCenter(unoAnchorPane);
            //this if for trying to accommodate the content en the BorderPane 
            BorderPane.setAlignment(unoAnchorPane, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

my first cuestion is what is the thing i am missing in the calling of the FXML for the contents of this ocupy the space available in the BorderPane?

my secon cuestion regards the change of FXML, when i pass fron one to another the change in the BorderPane is in a instant and looks very bad is there a way for making the transicion like one where the content of a FXML that is call push the content of the FXML in the center?, it doesn't have to be very elaborated just make the transition a little better

EDIT

i got a cordinator class where i send and recive parameters for all the FXML and where i declare the methods of calling new FXML, so i have a cordinator class, a FXML root with its controller and two FXML and its controllers with different things in each one, this two FXML are the ones that change in the BorderPane center of the root

this is the coordinator class

```
//Variables
        private Stage primaryStage;
        private BorderPane rootLayout;

    /**
     * launh 
     * @param primaryStage
     *  
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        // Inicializa la escena
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
        this.primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        //star method 
        iniLogin();
    }

     /**
     *load the root scene
     */
    public void iniLogin(){
        try {
            // Carga el loader.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(com.aohys.rehabSys.MVC.Coordinador.class.getResource(
                    "VistaControlador/Pricipal/Principal.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
            //the root scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            // Da acceso al programa principal.
            PrincipalController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.pasoPrincipal(this, primaryStage);
            primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
            // Muesta la escena,
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

after this method there are two identical methods like the one at the beginning where i call the 2 changing FXML call LanzaUno, LanzaDos

this is my rood FXML controler

```
public class PrincipalController implements Initializable {
    //variable of the coordinator class
    private Coordinador cordi;
    private Stage stage;

    /**
     * method for passing parameters to the FXML
     * @param cordi
     * @param stage 
     */
    public void pasoPrincipal(Coordinador cordi, Stage stage) {
        this.cordi = cordi;
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    //FXML in root 
    @FXML private Button btt1;
    @FXML private Button btt2;
    @FXML public static StackPane stackPane;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        //Call the firts FXML
        btt1.setOnAction((evento)->{
            cordi.lanzaUno();
        });

        //Call the second FXML
        btt2.setOnAction((evento)->{
            cordi.lanzaDos();
        });
    }
```

for the moment the controllers on the two FXML dont do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on [Adam Bien's AfterburnerFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafx-productivity-2345000.html) library for managing dependency injection and controllers in your application. It has changed my life. :)

For transitions, I use this code. It is a nice fade-out/fade-in from one screen to the next. In this case, `stackPane` is a `StackPane` in the center of your `BorderPane` defined in your FXML.

Here is a simple FXML with the aforementioned stackPane:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.tada.gui.tada.TadaPresenter">
   <center>
      <StackPane fx:id="stackPane" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="320.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

And the setScreen method that changes to the new one passed in:

```
/**
 * Set Screen 
 * 
 * @param view
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean setScreen(Parent view) {       
    final DoubleProperty opacity = stackPane.opacityProperty();

    if (!stackPane.getChildren().isEmpty()) {    //if there is more than one screen
        Timeline fade = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)),
                new KeyFrame(new Duration(TRANSITION_TIMER), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                        stackPane.getChildren().remove(0);        //remove the displayed screen
                        stackPane.getChildren().add(0, view);     //add the screen
                        Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline(
                                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)),
                                new KeyFrame(new Duration(TRANSITION_TIMER), new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)));
                        fadeIn.play();
                    }
                }, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)));
        fade.play();

    } else {
        stackPane.setOpacity(0.0);
        stackPane.getChildren().add(view);       //no one else been displayed, then just show
        Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)),
                new KeyFrame(new Duration(TRANSITION_TIMER), new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)));
        fadeIn.play();
    }
    return true;
}
```

You'll also need this in your controller...

```
private static final double TRANSITION_TIMER = 200;
```

EDIT:

I tried to put together a very basic "application". It is rudimentary, but I think it does a good job of illustrating the use of AfterburnerFX and the screen fade transition. There is a lot more to AfterburnerFX. I just used the view switching without the dependency injection, which is very important when you start wanting to work on objects in your application. Also, property binding is very important for a good UX.  Anyway, Here is a link to [my example](https://github.com/nevisnor/JavaFXExampleApp) on GitHub.

Comment: i definitly will check afterburnerFX, how do i implement the method you provide?, im goin to edit the question for more detials on how to implement you method, but in short the thing is i got a cordinator class where i send and recive parameters for all the FXML and where i declare the methods of calling new FXML, so i have a cordinator class, a FXML root with its controller and two FXML and its controllers with different things in each one, this two FXML are the ones that change in the BorderPane center of the root

Comment: @CorrOrtiz, I edited my answer to point you to a very simple example application on GitHub. I hope it is helpful to you.